# R how to make a scatterplot where y-values are strewn across multiple columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, multiple-columns, scatter-plot

I have a df with n=1136 rows each representing a subject. I am trying to create a scatterplot series for each subject with the x-values representing time intervals and the y-values representing the actual readings. In this case, we are just assuming that each reading was taken in 15 minute intervals. Lost as to how to even go about doing this without having to create individual. scatterplots for each subject.

| Study ID | Reading 1 | Reading 2 | Reading 3 | .... Reading 50 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 45 | 23 |  |  |
| 124 | 56 | 45 |  |  |
| 125 | 912 | 56 |  |  |

I've tried combining all the readings into a single column but realized that I would be creating over 1,000 scatterplots to capture the entire data set.

Comment: According to the question, you want a scatterplot for each subject. That would mean *n=1136* plots. Is this it?

Comment: Do you want to explore the temporal pattern in your data? A series of 50 `boxplots` (one for each of the 50 readings) or a `stripchart` with appropriate `jitter` might be helpful. Or you might look into running a regression and display its results.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a `ggplot2`/`dplyr` solution. I agree with other commenters that making 1100+ individual plots is not realistic. It may be better to plot everyone in one plot. If each reading is a 15-minute interval (e.g., `Reading1` represents 0 minutes to 15 minutes), then you will need to lengthen your data and combine all readings into one long column. Once the readings are combined into one column, you can transform that column into 15-minute intervals to better represent your x-axis.

```
library(tidyverse)
StudyID <- c(100:110)
Reading1 <- sample(20:100, 11, T); Reading2 <- sample(20:50, 11, T); Reading3 <- sample(10:30, 11, T)
Reading4 <- sample(20:100, 11, T); Reading5 <- sample(20:50, 11, T); Reading6 <- sample(10:30, 11, T)

df <- data.frame(StudyID, Reading1, Reading2, Reading3, Reading4, Reading5, Reading6) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -StudyID, names_to = "time") %>%
  mutate(StudyID = factor(StudyID)) %>%
  mutate(time = as.numeric(str_replace(time, "Reading", ""))) %>%
  mutate(time = time*15) %>%
  mutate(lowertime = time-15) %>%
  mutate(timeinterval = paste0(lowertime,"-",time))

ggplot(df, aes(x = timeinterval, y = value
               , color = StudyID # <- remove this to prevent each subject getting its own color
               )) +
  geom_point() + 
  ylab("Reading Value") + xlab("Time Interval in Minutes") + 
  ggtitle("Reading Plot") + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Absolutely fantastic; just what I was trying to do!